# The limit of $a_1^{a_2^{.^{.^{.^{a_n}}}}}-a_n^{a_{n-1}^{.^{.^{.^{a_1}}}}}$ as $n\to\infty$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

If this is a duplicate in any way, I'm sorry.

### The Question:

> For what $(a_i)_{i\in \Bbb N}\in \Bbb R_+^{\Bbb N}$ does
>
> $$L:=\lim_{n\to \infty}a_1^{a_2^{.^{.^{.^{a_n}}}}}-a_n^{a_{n-1}^{.^{.^{.^{a_1}}}}}$$
>
> exist and what values does $L$ take?

### Thoughts:

Of course, $L$ exists and would be $0$ when $a_i=1$ for all $i\in\Bbb N$. Also $L=1$ if
$$a_i=\begin{cases}
2 &: i=1 \\
1 &: i\neq 1.
\end{cases}$$

Comment: I'm tempted to say that $L=0$ when $a_i=a_1$ for all $i\in \Bbb N$.

Comment: I think $L$ would be $0$ as well if all $a_i$ are equal, right?

Comment: With complex exponents and complex bases, there is always the question of multivalues. How do you pick them?

Comment: I don't know if the limit is defined if two consecutive $a_i$ are zero. Because, what is $0^0$?

Comment: I forgot about that, @Arthur.

Comment: What would you suggest, @Arthur?

Comment: @Shaun May be restrict $a_i$ to be positive real number for each $i$ ?

Comment: Since $(a_i) = (x,1,1,\ldots) \leadsto L = x - 1$, so all $L > -1$ is possible.

Comment: Of similar flavor: [The least value of $b$ such that $2^{3^{\cdots^a}}\leq b^{(b-1)^{\cdots^2}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/612967)

Comment: What would be interesting is if both of the power towers tended towards infinity but their difference did not, excluding the trivial constant sequence case.

Answer (score 2):

This is a partial answer, it address what value of $L$ can take.
It turns out $L$ can take any real number as value.

For simplicity of typesetting, I will use Knuth's up-arrow notation to represent any tower of exponentiation. Furthermore, we will assume the up-arrows are right-associative. More precisely,

$$a_1 \uparrow a_2 \uparrow \cdots \uparrow a_n
\;=\; a_1 \uparrow \left( a_2 \uparrow \left(\cdots \uparrow a_n\right)\right)
\;\stackrel{def}{=}\;a_1^{a_2^{.^{.^{.^{a_n}}}}}
$$

For any $z \in \mathbb{R}$, rewrite $z$ as $x-y$ for some $x, y > 0$. Let $(y_k)_{k \ge 0}$ be any sequence of positive numbers such that $y_0 = 1$ and $y_n \to y$ as $n \to \infty$.
Consider the sequence $(a_k)_{k > 0}$ defined by

$$a_1 = x,\quad a_2 = 1\quad\text{and}\quad a_{n+2} = y_{n}^{1/y_{n-1}}\quad\text{for}\quad n > 0 $$

It is easy to see for any $n > 0$,

$$a_1 \uparrow a_2 \uparrow \cdots \uparrow a_{n+2}
= x \uparrow ( 1 \uparrow ( \cdots ) ) = x \uparrow 1  = x$$
Furthermore,
$$\begin{align}
  a_{n+2} \uparrow \cdots \uparrow a_5 \uparrow a_4 \uparrow a_3 \uparrow a_2 \uparrow a_1
&=  y_n^{1/y_{n-1}} \uparrow \cdots \uparrow y_3^{1/y_2} \uparrow y_2^{1/y_1}\uparrow y_1^{1/y_0} \uparrow 1 \uparrow x\\
&=  y_n^{1/y_{n-1}} \uparrow \cdots \uparrow y_3^{1/y_2} \uparrow y_2^{1/y_1}\uparrow y_1 \uparrow 1 \\
&=  y_n^{1/y_{n-1}} \uparrow \cdots \uparrow y_3^{1/y_2} \uparrow y_2^{1/y_1}\uparrow y_1 \\
&= y_n^{1/y_{n-1}} \uparrow \cdots \uparrow y_3^{1/y_2} \uparrow y_2 \\
&\;\;\vdots\\
&= y_n 
\end{align}
$$
For this particular choice of $a_k$, we have
$$L = \lim_{n\to\infty} 
\left( 
a_1 \uparrow a_2 \uparrow \cdots \uparrow a_{n+2} -
a_{n+2} \uparrow a_{n+1} \uparrow \cdots \uparrow a_1
\right)
 = \lim_{n\to\infty} (x - y_n) = x - y = z$$
From this, we can conclude $L$ can take any real number as value.